What does Hinduism say about everything boiling down to polarities (opposites)?
I asked this question on the Philosophy StackExchange, What philosophies don't say things boil down to polarities (opposites)?, as some belief systems have deep belief that everything is on a spectrum of polarity/opposites.
What does Hinduism say about polarities/opposites? Does everything have an opposite? If so, how (I have several examples in my linked question, of what I think cannot be polarities).
